# Question around smart contract with fees

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment

Working on our first smart contract/token deployment. We're trying to avoid team tokens/marketing wallets/etc. and instead use a small transaction fee for the dev/team. We've tested in Ropsten, and thus far everything is working except the transaction fee piece (using an existing contract to get the steps down).

I noticed that many of these types of contracts have similar fee wallets - there are no ERC-20 token transactions, just internal transactions. Is this a specific type of wallet/address? Here's a quick example from this morning:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x10d599336a3b8328875d29a12d3149fe52d5a149#internaltx

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you click some of the internal transactions, you'll notice that there are normal ERC20 transfers in the "parent" transaction. The concept is "internal" transaction simply means that the transfer is done inside another transaction, and otherwise there is nothing special about it - they work exactly the same way as if they were not internal transactions, but they are simply displayed differently since they are a part of another transaction.

So you initiate a transaction from your wallet to a contract, and inside that transaction the contract calls multiple other contracts. Each such call to external contracts is sometimes referred to as "internal transaction".